# The in-app price conset sheet is not shown when increasing the price of a recurring subscription on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I'm using the `in_app_purchase` package for Flutter and i'm currently trying to tackle the subscription price change for Apple, specifically the price increase scenario. As described in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-subscriptions/manage-pricing-for-auto-renewable-subscriptions), user must consent in case any of the following applies:

```
- The subscriber is located in a region that requires consent for 
  any price changes.
- The price increase is:
    * More than 50% of the current price; and
    * The difference in price exceeds approximately US$5 per period 
      for non-annual subscriptions, or US$50 per year for annual
      subscriptions.
- The subscriber experienced a price increase for that subscription
  within the past 12 months.
```

I've made a recurring monthly subscription, set up the renew period for the sandbox accounts to `3 minutes`, set the price to `€9.99` and subscribed to it with my sandbox account. Then i've increased the price of this subscription to `€24.99`, but the in-app price consent sheet was never shown, even after multiple renews.

Edit: I've forgot to mention that the subscription is still in the `Ready to Submit` status, since i've not published my app